# how to allow angular 5 web app to open in multiple tab in same browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to open angular 5 app in multiple tab in chrome. 
Is their any method and caching process that can help in this process.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open angular application to other tab it will behave similar as refresh.
Based on the routing module it will load the component or modules.

If your routing is secured using the guard then it will redirect to base URL or Login page as per the implementation, because it cannot access authentication details from previous tab.

To keep user loggedIn your API must recognize the USER. This can be achieved by Token based authentication or by setting browser cookies.[Angular Security - Authentication With JSON Web Tokens (JWT): The Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/)